How to use custom ReactNativeHost to load different bundles for multiple activities in react-native
Custom ReactNativeHost, initialized in activity, will report an error
package com.awesomeprojecttwoactivity;

import android.app.Application;

import com.awesomeprojecttwoactivity.BuildConfig;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomReactNativeHost extends ReactNativeHost {
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
        List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
        // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
        // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
        return packages;
    }

    public CustomReactNativeHost(Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSBundleFile() {
        return "assets://index.android.bundle";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
        return "index";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }
}

package com.awesomeprojecttwoactivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  private CustomReactInstanceManager customManager;
  private ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost;
  private ReactRootView rootView;
  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "AwesomeProjectTwoActivity";
  }

  /**
   * Returns the instance of the {@link ReactActivityDelegate}. Here we use a util class {@link
   * DefaultReactActivityDelegate} which allows you to easily enable Fabric and Concurrent React
   * (aka React 18) with two boolean flags.
   */
//  @Override
//  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
//    return new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
//        this,
//        getMainComponentName(),
//        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
//        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled());
////    return new ReactActivityDelegate(
////            this,
////            getMainComponentName()
////    );
//  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CustomReactNativeHost reactNativeHost = new CustomReactNativeHost(getApplication());
    System.out.println("error1");
    ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = reactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager();
    System.out.println("error2");

    ReactRootView reactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
    reactRootView.startReactApplication(
            reactInstanceManager,
            "AwesomeProjectTwoActivity  ", // 对应 JS 中注册的组件名称
            null
    );

    setContentView(reactRootView);
  }
}


package com.awesomeprojecttwoactivity;

import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.util.List;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isNewArchEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean isHermesEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
        }

//        @Nullable
//        @Override
//        protected String getJSBundleFile() {
//            String path = "assets://index.android.bundle";
//            return path;
//        };
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

//  @Override
//  public void onCreate() {
//    super.onCreate();
//    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
//    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
//      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
//      DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load();
//    }
//    ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
//  }
}


Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libjscexecutor.so" not found
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.SystemDelegate.loadLibrary(SystemDelegate.java:24)
at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:52)
at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:30)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:869)
at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.loadLibrary(JSCExecutor.java:24)
at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.(JSCExecutor.java:20)
at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.loadLibrary(JSCExecutor.java:24)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.getDefaultJSExecutorFactory(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:373)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:325)
at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:96)
at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:42)
at com.facebook.react.ReactDelegate.loadApp(ReactDelegate.java:121)
at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.loadApp(ReactActivityDelegate.java:114)
at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onCreate(ReactActivityDelegate.java:109)
at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:46)
at com.awesomeprojecttwoactivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8109) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8083) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3489) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3676) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2116) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7904) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
